# Why am I not getting slope of a horizontal line = 0?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the slope of my data in Matlab through "polyfit"  command.

```
x = 1:38; y = -60*ones(1,38);
p_fit = polyfit(x,y,1);
slope = p_fit(1);
```

As per my knowledge, since `y` has constant values, I am expecting slope to be zero. But I am getting a value in `10^-16`. So please help me in correcting myself.

The values of `y` is in dB domain. SO will this be any problem ? or any other reason.

Thanks

Comment: `1e-16` isn't close enough to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB runs on double precision floating point arithmetic if you don't tell it to do otherwise, and `10^-16` is reasonably well within the expected error.

If you want to get into the specifics (and you really should), have a look at ["What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

**Update**:

With regards to your comment, the boundaries you mention are at least 10 orders of magnitude bigger than the error you are seeing, so as long as this stays that way, you really need not worry about the small error.

Comment: Thanks.. you are right. But I am working on very sensitive datas. So I would like to distinguish betweeen the slope values.(To disinguish if slope is >-1 or >10^-6 or -1<slope<10^-6  ). So is it possible to distinguish between these values ?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if you need ways to work around that, you will need to tell us why such a small error is a problem in your case (that is, tell us what you need to do with that slope) and it's very likely that you'll get a satisfactory answer.