# Non 0 slope for horizontal line in sklearn linear_model

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have the code below which returns a non 0 slope for a horizontal line of data. What am I missing?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
X=[[733803], [733831], [733862], [733892], [733923], [733953], [733984], [734015], [734045], [734076], [734106], [734137], [734168], [734196]]
y=[0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17,0.17]
reg.fit(X,y)
print(reg.coef_)
```

Returns [-3.06072077e-32] but should be 0?

```
plt.scatter(X, y,color='g')
plt.plot(X, reg.predict(X),color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a double precision floating point issue as per  [Why am I not getting slope of a horizontal line = 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649864/why-am-i-not-getting-slope-of-a-horizontal-line-0).

Substituting floats for integers returns a 0 slope.